# Python: checking for executable

Tags: python

```
is_exec = lambda x: subprocess.call("type " + x, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) == 0 and (os.path.isfile(x) and os.access(x, os.X_OK))
```

I came across this code and it works fine but is it redundant?

Isnt `is_exec = lambda x: os.access(x, os.X_OK)` sufficient?

Question: Is there a case where `is_exec = lambda x: os.access(x, os.X_OK)` isnt catching but the first one does?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is redundant. Both pieces of code work just as well; only the second is more concise. The difference is that one actually does a test, the other checks properties. Besides, avoid the first one anyway as it may be vulnerable to arbitrary code execution.

Comment: The first looks like a backdoor if you aren't carefully vetting the value of `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a subtle difference here -- in the first call, this will also detect shell built-ins, for example:

```
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
$ echo $?
0
```

But there is no actual `cd` executable as such, so you can't check it explicitly with `os.access()`. That said, I believe it should actually be

```
is_exec = lambda x: subprocess.call("type " + x, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) == 0 or (os.path.isfile(x) and os.access(x, os.X_OK))
```

Note that the middle operator is now `or`. Also, the subprocess pipes seem a bit superfluous here, and there is the caveat that it can be used as a shell injection to consider too.

All in all, if you only care about verifying exeutable *files*, then ditching the first bit is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Both require `os.access(x, os.X_OK)` to return True. However, in addition to performing some unnecessary tests before calling `os.access`, the first opens you up to a shell injection attack unless you carefully screen the value of `x` before using it. Using `shell=True` with `subprocess.call` simply passes a string to the shell for execution. If the value of `x` is carefully constructed, you end up executing more than just the `type` command. For example:

```
x = "somefile.txt; rm foo.txt"
subprocess.call("type " + x, shell=True,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

will pass the string "type somefile.txt; rm foo.txt" to the shell, resulting in two commands, not just one, in being executed.